# Почему get запрос возвращает (failed) net::ERR_FAILED?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, axios

Есть следующий метод позволяющий скачать файл с сервера

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("{itemId:int}"), HttpGet]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "Content-Disposition")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment([FromUri]int id, [FromUri]int itemId)
{
    var response= Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    //инициализация переменных filename & byteArray
    var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
    response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", mimeType);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName),
    };
        
    return response;
}
```

на клиенте для выполнения запросов используется [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios),

```
axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" })
```

Запрос на сервер приходит и отрабатывает без ошибок, но скачивание файла не происходит в консоли разработчика появляется ошибка **(failed) net::ERR_FAILED**, а самое странное что если открыть приватное окно в браузере и выполнить тот же самый запрос то все нормально, файл скачивается без проблем. Подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

Заголовки запроса:

```
GET /api/processes/1029/documents/16310 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.7.20.25
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer ***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://10.7.20.25/aist/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Заголовки ответа:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 8577108
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Имя файла.pdf"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2020 02:27:45 GMT
```

Comment: если в приватном режиме все ок, то мешать можешь какое-нибудь из запущенных расширений